# What do two bytes after e0 in JPEG header indicate?

Tags: image, jpeg, hexdump

hex dump of a jpeg image :

[image]

Here is a hex dump of a jpeg image . What do two bytes 09 3a indicate?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JPEG_File_Interchange_Format), `09 3a` indicates the length of the segment, excluding the `ff e0` that immediately precedes it.

The article states that:

> The bytes s1 and s2 are taken together to represent a big-endian 16-bit integer specifying the length of the following "data bytes" plus the 2 bytes used to represent the length.

So in your case, it indicates a "data bytes" length of 2,360 bytes.